# How to specify the unit information prior

Tags: r, bayesian, bic, unit-information-prior, inla

Continuing on from this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26329/what-is-a-unit-information-prior) and this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26339/the-unit-information-prior-and-its-bic-approximation) re BIC and its approximation to the Bayes factor with a unit information prior [(Kass & Wasserman, 1995)](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2291327?uid=3737536&uid=2&uid=4&sid=47698890289477), I'm trying to quantify this relationship as a stepping stone into Bayesian stats. So far, my calculation of the BIC approximation of the Bayes factor (based upon my impression of [Wagenmakers 2007](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2291327?uid=3737536&uid=2&uid=4&sid=47698890289477)) is linearly related to my Bayes factor that is calculated from my interpretation of the unit information prior using the [INLA](http://www.r-inla.org/home) package in R. Good start! However, my BIC Bayes factor is ~ 3 times smaller than the Bayes factor calculated with INLA and I'm not sure why.

The prior I've used in the "**inla**" function is N(0, 1/(variance * n)) and this seems to me the likely place where I'm out. I'm not sure how I got the multiply by n in the formula, but it appears to work... roughly. Kass and Wasserman have N(0, variance / n) which when converted to precision would be N(0, n / variance), but this gives me a less good relationship.

Help based on other Bayesian packages is also welcome.

*EDIT*

```
*Deleted code, see below answer instead*
```

*EDIT*

So I'm pretty sure I've figured out the one sample case. I would still appreciate help for the two sample case and the regression case (which I'll start working on now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out for the one sample case after updating my knowledge with [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/) and the rjags code contained within. The model specification I've used below gives me a slope of ~ 1 and intercept of ~ 0 when the BIC Bayes factor approximation is regressed against the Bayes factor from the rjags model.

```
model {
# Likelihood:
  for( i in 1 : N ) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm( mu , tau ) # tau is precision, not SD
  }
# Prior:
  tau ~ dnorm( yprec , (yprec^2)/2 )
  mu ~ dnorm( amu , atau )
#Hyperprior
  atau <- tauModel[ modelIndex ]
  amu  <- muModel[ modelIndex ]
  tauModel[1] <- 10000
  tauModel[2] <- yprec
  muModel[1] <- 0
  muModel[2] <- ymean   

#Hyperhyperprior
  modelIndex ~ dcat( modelProb[] )
  modelProb[1] <- 0.5
  modelProb[2] <- 0.5
}
```

And the input data:

```
y = rnorm( n=200 , mean=1 , sd=1 )
yprec = 1/var(y)
ymean = mean(y)
```

And for linear regression:

```
model {
  for( i in 1 : Ndata ) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm( mu[i] , tau )
    mu[i] <- beta0 + beta1 * x[i]
  }
  beta0 ~ dnorm( b0mu , b0tau )
  beta1 ~ dnorm( b1mu , b1tau )
  tau ~ dgamma( yrprec , (yrprec^2)/2 )

#Hyperprior
  b0tau <- b0tauModel[ modelIndex ]
  b0mu  <- b0muModel[ modelIndex ]
  b1tau <- b1tauModel[ modelIndex ]
  b1mu  <- b1muModel[ modelIndex ]

  b0muModel[1] <- zymean
  b0tauModel[1] <- yrprec
  b1muModel[1] <- 0
  b1tauModel[1] <- 10000 

  b0muModel[2] <- xbeta0
  b0tauModel[2] <- yrprec
  b1muModel[2] <- xbeta1
  b1tauModel[2] <- yrprec

#Hyperhyperprior
  modelIndex ~ dcat( modelProb[] )
  modelProb[1] <- 0.5
  modelProb[2] <- 0.5
}
```

Regression input data:

```
x <- rnorm(50, sd=30) + 1:50  ;  y <- rnorm(50, sd=30) + 1:50
nSubj <- length(x)
xM = mean( x ) ; xSD = sd( x ); yM = mean( y ) ; ySD = sd( y )
zx = ( x - xM ) / xSD         ; zy = ( y - yM ) / ySD
#
lm1 <- lm(zy ~ zx); slm1 <- summary(lm1)
yrprec <- 1/var(resid(lm1))
zymean <- mean(zy)
xbeta0 <- coef(slm1)[1,1]      ; xbeta1 <- coef(slm1)[2,1]
```

Framework for these models is from [Kruschke](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com.au/)

Comment: Could you please *explain* the code rather then providing code-only answer?